# Generate unique alpha-numeric object ID, like Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I already asked what I needed at the title. I want to generate using either  PHP or javascript.

I think the class name and some properties are used to build the objectId but someone may already know how its done that could share here?

Comment: Why? Just generate a GUID.

Comment: I need to generate something like "xWMyZ4YEGZ" which serves as a unique identifier for each record.

Comment: yeah, a GUID will fulfil that requirement...

Comment: GUID are normally long...how to keep them to 10 characters long?

Comment: why does it need to be 10 chars? You can also use a millisecond timestamp

Comment: The shorter it is the easier to work with. I think it is similar to tinyurls. I can use the table name and integer id or plus the timestamp to create one unique identifier. I need it because I will be storing all rows from different tables into one sqlite table and to prevent any duplicate identifier why I need the same mechanism. If I just rely on the integer id there will be duplicates. When fetching it from the database I don't want to indicate what table name, all I need is the unique id generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parse Server generates the `objectId`. It is a randomly generated String of 10 chars length. You can see their implementation at `cryptoUtils.newObjectId()`. From the code we can conclude that they are not enforcing uniqueness.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/cryptoUtils.js

Answer (score 2):

Parse is probably using ids generated in Mongodb. They are not random and can be potentially predicted :

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value
>   consisting of a 4-byte timestamp
>   (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte
>   machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a
>   3-byte counter

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Comment: This is longer than this "xWMyZ4YEGZ"